raspberry pi 5 8 G Ram go down after 2 second green
I am trying to turn my Pi 5 8gb ram on but it is not turning on. Only the red LED remains on without blinking. The green LED is on during startup for 2 seconds and then turns off.
I have tried many power sources, it was working fine but suddenly started doing this problem. Yesterday it showed the same problem but was working again after some time but this time it does not.
now I'm using 5v 5a power sources
How do I fix this problem?

Search for raspberry pi boot problems.

See RPI 4B, PI5 and RPI 400 Boot Problems

it was working fine but suddenly started doing this problem usually there's something that has changed, computers are not known for behaving differently when nothing changes - unless the sd card has failed in the meantime
